# Occupation Number of Tomonaga-Luttinger Liquid away from the Fermi Wavevector

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, many-body, tomonaga-luttinger-liquid

[I have read that, near $k_F$,](http://qpt.physics.harvard.edu/phys268/Lec3_Luttinger_liquids.pdf) the occupation number of a Tomonaga-Luttinger liquid goes as

$ n(k)\sim -\textrm{sgn}(k-k_F)|k-k_F|^{(K+1/K)/2-1}$

where

$K=\left(1+\frac{Uv_F}{\pi}\right)^{-1/2}$

However, I am curious what would happen when $k<<k_F$ or $k>>k_F$. Logically, the occupation number for the former should go to unity and that of the latter should go to zero, but I was wondering if there is anyway to explicitly show this? That is, is there some way to derive a Tomonaga-Luttinger $n(k)$ such that it explains the physics in all regimes of $k$?

Answer (score 1):

I guess finding occupation number for all k within the framework of Tomonaga -Luttinger liquid won't be justifiable. Because in the derivation of the theory we have added unphysical momenta of negative energies. So the theory is valid only in the low energy regime around the Fermi point.